layout.tsx is not a client component, but nextjs say it's a client component and I cannot export metadata
My app was working fine, but suddenly nextjs says that layout.tsx file is a client component and I cannot export metadata from. Also I have implemented the navbar above the children like that:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

import "@/styles/globals.css";

import type { Metadata } from "next";

import Nav from "@/components/nav";

const interFont = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Nextjs",
  description: "My app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={interFont.className}>
        <Nav /> {/* btw navbar uses react hooks */}
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

I tried restarting the server and also removing the .next folder

Add use client at the top of <Nav/>. make only nav to client component
nav.tsx
"use client"; // This makes Nav a client component

import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Nav() {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav>
      <button onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)}>Toggle Menu</button>
      {menuOpen && <div>Menu Content</div>}
    </nav>
  );
}


